# EXPRESS (dml) and PASCAL

Tags: express, data-modeling, pascal

Is EXPRESS based upon, or does it use entirely PASCAL?

Additionally, any simple ways to stringify and/or create EXPRESS back from a string (marshal/unmarshal)?

Edit00:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPRESS_(data_modeling_language) for reference.

Comment: Neither. It has some superficial, but unrelated syntax here and there it seems.

Answer (score 1):

No, the language in the wikipedia article is not Pascal. The syntax is probably inspired by Pascal or Algol, or even Ada, but it is most definitely not Pascal.